# What is the difference between Facades\Session and HttpFoundation\Session

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm a little bit confused when I use session in my project. When I use it, it shows two types of session

```
1. use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session
2. use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session
```

What is the difference between these two? And where/how can I use these, or can I use these two at the same time?
Thanks.

Comment: @all what is wrong in my question?

Comment: I think this is mostly a lack of a fundamental understanding of facades and why to use them. [Give the Documentation page concerning Facades a good read](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session`, you are using a Facade.

**What is a Facade?**

In short a Facade gives you a pretty static interface for interacting with Laravel. Rather of instantiating a class, passing in all it dependencies, etc, instead you use a Facade and behind the scenes Laravel will take care of the process of instantiating the class and resolving any dependencies out of the IoC Container.

See [How Facades Work](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades#how-facades-work) in Laravel Docs.

The `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session` file is just this:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;
/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Session\SessionManager
 * @see \Illuminate\Session\Store
 */
class Session extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'session';
    }
}
```

See the `session` string it returns? Well Laravel will take that and search in its IoC Container for the concrete implementation, in this case an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session` class;

**In conclusion**

You can use one or another.

If you want to use the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session` you will have to inject it in the constructor or new it up and pass all its dependencies.

If you go with `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session` just call the static methods and you are ready to go.

Small note: Some people agree that facades are a bad design patern, but that is a whole diferent battle, in the end it is up to you to make the decision of whether use them or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Facades provide a "static" interface to classes that are available in the application's service container.

What this means, is that facades are wrapper classes, designed for Laravel specifically, which provide simple and Laravel-consistent access to the parent classes. Also, the facades are inserted in the app's service container, which makes sure the facade is only loaded once, so it's available in your whole app, as the same instance.

When you are using classes, which also come with a facade for Laravel, using the facade is the simpliest way to go.

The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades) explain this feature quite well, so you should really take a look at it.